# tcl no such file or directory

Tags: tcl

I am running this script `nmrCube.tcl` for generating 3D box from NMR data.

I initially had problem with Library before which is now sorted

While running the script I get this, (even though it is indeed there):

```
Error in startup script: couldn't read file "“./nmrCube.tcl”": no such file or directory
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32806964/7552

Answer (score 1):

`“”` ... looks like copy pasted commands from a silly website that replaced `""` with pretty quotes. Use `""` instead.

Comment: probably as they are part of the error message. But unsure how to get rid of them since I do ./nmrCube.tcl to execute the script Thanks

Comment: @user5381305 you are saying you run `./nmrCube.tcl`, and it runs `“./nmrCube.tcl”`?

Comment: @user5381305 then you'll have to fix that script somehow. Where did you get it from?

Comment: from the developer of the program it starts like this:

Comment: !/bin/sh
# The next line restarts using nmrWish \
exec nmrWish “$0” — “$@”

set auto_path “[split $env(TCLPATH) :] $auto_path”
set ARGV [concat $argv0 $argv]
set ARGC [llength $ARGV]

if {[info exists env(NMRTXT)]} \
{
set tStr ” ($env(NMRTXT)/rgb.txt).”
} \
else \
{
set tStr “.”

Comment: Ok, just edit that file and replace every pretty quote you see with `""`.

Comment: @user5381305 there are other Unicode characters in that script, like the dash instead of hyphens. Are you sure you didn't copy this from a website, even if it was the developer's website?

Comment: yes it was copied from his website

Comment: @user5381305 sigh. Ask the dev to provide the script in plain text, then. Or look for a download link somewhere. Whatever CMS he's using has badly mangled the script.